# RSpec: Mocks, Stubs and Verification

Tags: ruby, testing, rspec, tdd, rspec-mocks

I'm writing a plugin for [Cinch](https://github.com/cinchrb/cinch/) (the IRC bot), and trying to write some RSpec tests for it.

However, I'm trying to get to grips with RSpec, and mocking out the external dependencies of this plugin. I want to test two different things for now - that it says hello to people, and that it keeps track of who it's said hello to.

So I've got a method, `say_hello`, which takes a `Cinch::Message`. What's the easiest way to mock this particular class? I'm used to Mockito and Java, so I'm used to making a mock of a particular class.

How can I make a mock of `Cinch::Message`? In my first test, I want to assert that the `reply` method is called on that message. In the next one, I just want it to respond like a `Cinch::Message` would, as I only care about the tracking the class does, not the interaction with the message.

I've only just started out with RSpec, so maybe I'm missing something fundamental. Should I be using a mock? A stub?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all documentation would be a nice start point, see: https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/v/2-11/docs/message-expectations

..and this is how your test could look:

```
it 'should call #reply on the message'
  message = double('cinch message')
  message.should_receive(:reply)
  object_under_test.say_hello(message)
end
```